# Many to Many EF LINQ

Tags: linq, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I have a database that has the following tables:

```
dbo.Administrator

dbo.Application

dbo.AdminApplication

dbo.Proficiency

dbo.ProficiencyLevel
```

- Administrators contain 1 to many Applications.  Application contains many administrators
- Applications contain 1 to many Proficiency(s)
- Proficiency contains 1 to many ProficiencyLevels

Using EF Code First, the AdminApplication is not mapped as an entity and this is what is causing me issues.  What I want to answer is the following:

**"Return all the ProficiencyLevels of the Administrator named "danhickman"**.

In SQL, the query would look like this:

```
Select * from dbo.ProficiencyLevel pl
inner join dbo.Proficiency p on p.Id = pl.ProficiencyId
inner join dbo.Application a on a.Id = p.ApplicationId
inner join dbo.AdminApplication aa on aa.ApplicationId = a.Id
inner join dbo.Administrator ad on ad.Id = aa.AdministratorId
where ad.Name = 'danhickman'
```

I solved this with the following C# code:

```
        public IQueryable<LobGame.Model.ProficiencyLevel> GetAllByAdminName(string administratorName)
    {
        var context = this.DbContext as LobGameDbContext;
        var admin = context.Administrators.Include(i => i.Applications).Include("Applications.Proficiencies").Include("Applications.Proficiencies.ProficiencyLevels").Single(o => o.Name == administratorName);
        List<LobGame.Model.ProficiencyLevel> list = new List<ProficiencyLevel>();
        foreach (var app in admin.Applications)
        {
            foreach (var prof in app.Proficiencies)
            {
                list.AddRange(prof.ProficiencyLevels);
            }
        }
        return list.AsQueryable();
    }
```

It bugs me that I have to foreach and add to a list.  I was unable to figure out a way to do this in a single LINQ statement.  any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     return context.Administrators
                   .Single(o => o.Name == administratorName)
                   .Applications
                   .SelectMany(app => app.Proficiencies)
                   .SelectMany(prof => prof.ProficiencyLevels)
                   .ToList()
                   .AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option using query syntax. This uses SelectMany under the covers.

```
var queryableList = 
  from admin in context.Administrators
  where admin.Name = administratorName
  from app in admin.Applications
  from proficiency in app.Proficiencies
  from level in proficiency.ProficiencyLevels
  select level;
```

Note: this will be an IQueryable, so you don't need the .ToList().AsQueryable().

Answer (score 1):

Use `SelectMany()`:

```
var queryableList = 
  context.Administrators.Single(o => o.Name.Equals(administratorName))
                        .SelectMany(adm => adm.Applications.Select(app => app.Proficiencies.SelectMany(prof => prof.ProficiencyLevels))).ToList().AsQueryable();
```